# System speed/memory considerations x86 vs. x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory, 64-bit, x86

Currently I have Windows Server 2008 x64 installed on my machine. I'm about to reinstall when R2 comes out (few more days). Since I still remember all the tweaking with various device drivers, I'm thinking of installing an x86 version which has better Vista x86 driver support (that are also compatible with WinSrv2k8 AFAIK).

I have 4GB of memory which should be utilised without a problem on both platforms.

**Would you suggest going to x86 or try the same driver hell all over again on x64? Would there be any significant speed issues? Memory issues?**

I am/will also running several VMs of various kinds (x86 and x64). I know my hardware supports running x64 guests in x86 hosts already, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of question I would suggest having a read of the [4sysops](http://4sysops.com/) posts on the recent x86 vs x64 discussions.

- [Windows 7 x64 or Windows 7 x86? My experiences with Vista 64-bit](http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-7-x64-or-windows-7-x86-my-experiences-with-vista-64-bit/)
- **[Windows 7: 64-bit or 32-bit? Memory and performance](http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-7-64-bit-or-32-bit-memory-and-performance/)**
- [Vista x86 or Vista x64? What about hardware compatibility?](http://4sysops.com/archives/vista-x86-or-vista-x64-what-about-hardware-compatibility/)
- [Poll: Vista x86 or Vista x64? What is your choice?](http://4sysops.com/archives/poll-vista-x86-or-vista-x64-what-is-your-choice/)

My suggestion? Since you are already running x64 then I would just stick with it. Majority of servers nowadays should all be on x64 technology. The idea of future proofing also comes to mind.

Comment: +1 for future-proofing

Answer (score 5):

You haven't got a choice if you're going Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2 is the first Windows OS platform to go 64-bit only.

Comment: I'm so glad someone posted that in a non-sarcastic way, I've been typing and backspacing for at least ten minutes on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

With 2008 R2, you're basically getting all of the baked in driver support that comes with Windows 7.  Chances are if your hardware isn't bleeding edge anymore, you'll have fairly good driver support in x64 right out of the box.

Comment: Well normally there's no BT/Wifi support out of the box for notebooks is it? I've never seen it so far. And there's other stuff with HP notebooks that's just PITA to install.

Answer (score 0):

sure. you can go ahead.
i have personally tested WinSrv2k8 x86 with 4gb ram with compatible vista drivers. everything works fine. all printer, scanner that support vista works well with win2k8.
i personally think you can give it a try. i am sure you will love it.